# KnockoutJs Cursor position lost parent click event

Tags: binding, click, knockout.js, lost-focus

**Nested div with click events.**

I have a couple nested divs which are bound to a common viewModel object which I am using knockoutjs to bind with. The parent and child divs have several bindings including a click event on the parent. The parent div click event acts a way to select the element showing some visual cues that are hidden by default as a result.

*The binding code is as follows:*

```
<div data-bind="foreach : cardElements">

        <div data-bind="if: isArea(),
                attr: { id : ElementName },
                visible: isArea(),
                click : selectElement.bind($data),
                css : { layoutContainer : isEditMode() && isSelected(),
                        drag: isEditMode(),
                        selectedElement : isSelected() && isEditMode() },
                style : defaultStyle()">

 ... visuals elided for clarity(hidden by default viewable when parent is selected)

        @* Regular display fields. *@
        <div data-bind="if: isInput(),
                    attr : { contenteditable : isEditMode() },
                    visible : isInput(),
                    css: { layoutDiv :  isEditMode() },
                    style: { cursor : 'text' },
                    text: Value">
        </div>


 ... visuals elided for clarity

    </div>
</div>
```

**Focus troubles after click event.**

Holding the mouse button down reveals the cursor (text cursor) showing in the contenteditable div where it is supposed to end up after the click. Upon release the focus is lost and the cursor is gone (I have also tried using an input element and the same problem occurs). The idea is that the mousedown/click should place the cursor at the desired position for typing text.

**Removal of the parent click event**

Removing the click event on the parent reveals that, without it,  the selecting inside the contenteditable div works as intended and typing can continue as normal after the click. However, the visual cues aren't set, of course which is the main job of the click event handler!

Does anyone know why the focus is lost during the click event?

**Maybe a hack could work**
One hack, which I haven't attempted yet, would be to set focus on the contenteditable div, based on the cursor position over top of the div itself. This doesn't seem to be a trivial hack nor do I know it is even possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on this subject.

**Getting closer perhaps**

I was able to narrow it down by doing a little of regression testing. If I remove the css style from the parent div it seems to click as usual.

removed the following:

```
 css : { layoutContainer : isEditMode() && isSelected(),
                        drag: isEditMode(),
                        selectedElement : isSelected() && isEditMode() },
```

This still leaves me with incomplete behavior.

**Could it be?**

It appears that when the parent class is added the focus is lost from the contenteditable div.

Here is a little more of the code that is used.
    ... // mapped functions.

```
this.isSelected = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    return (this === viewModel.selectedCardElement());
}, this);

this.selectElement = function (element, evt) {
     viewModel.selectedCardElement(element);
},
```

The **selectElement** is the called function and note that **isSelected** is a dependentObservable attached to the card elements that are bound in the template. It seems to me that as soon as the **viewModel.selectedCardElement** is set the caret position focus and  are lost in the view.